# Office Web Viewer Error - We're sorry, but for some reason we can't open this for you

Tags: html, web, powerpoint

I am trying to use Office Web Viewer and always get this error:

**An error occurred
We're sorry, but for some reason we can't open this for you.**

I read documentation. I tried to use the same PPTX as in example, just on my host and nothing.

One of the URL i use:

```
https://online.bleumarin.agency/storage/upload/documents/66578-tool-532t_sutter.pptx - My, Doesn't work.
-
http://video.ch9.ms/build/2011/slides/TOOL-532T_Sutter.pptx  - WORKS
```

I am using and embed (or iframe) tag with my URL encoded:

```
<embed 
src="https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/view.aspx?src=https%3A%2F%2Fonline.bleumarin.agency%2Fstorage%2Fupload%2Fdocuments%2F66578-tool-532t_sutter.pptx" 
frameborder="0" 
width="100%" height="100%"></embed>
```

Can someone give me an advice, or explication? WHYYY?? T_T

Comment: httpS is most likely the problem. See if the problem goes away if you use only http.

Comment: @JohnKorchok, disabled foce https, the same :/

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Send microsoft to the ****, Use Google <3

```html
<iframe width="100%" height="500px" src="https://docs.google.com/gview?url=https://online.bleumarin.agency/test&embedded=true"></iframe>
```